# Importing a subpackage from a git repository using poetry

Tags: python, git, pip, package, python-poetry

I have two Poetry projects in separate repositories. Project B is a library used by Project A.

When I moved Project B from a setuptools-based project to a Poetry project, I started experiencing this error:

```
    from project_b.layer.obstacle import generate_obstacle_layer, Inputs, Outputs
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_b.layer'
```

I see the following installed into Project A's `.venv`:

```
project_a/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/project_b$ tree 
.
├── cli.py
├── general.py
└── utils.py
```

Despite the fact that Project B's structure is:

```
project_b$ tree -L 1
.
├── adapters/
├── algorithms/
├── cli.py
├── general.py
├── __init__.py
├── layer/
├── tools/
└── utils.py
```

My `pyproject.toml` in Project A brings in Project B as a dependency like so:

```yaml
[tool.poetry.dependencies.project_b]
git = "https://github.com/nckswt/project_b"
rev = "08b47ae46048b472925f5f264c887988a3670ae7"
```

What do I need to do to be able to support modules deeper than simply the top level? I've got easily 50+ StackOverflow / Github Issues links I've read through and haven't been able to solve this issue at all.